# Javascript game something wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML and javascript code for a little game but there is something wrong, i searched everywhere to find the problem, but can't find it!? Really frustrating!
Hope you guys can help me?

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Programmeren</title>
<link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="static/js/game.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <h1>program</h1>
    <div id="berichtvenster">

    </div>
  </header>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Copyleft <span class="copy">&copy;</span> 2013, all wrongs reversed.</p>
</footer>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';

    var toonBoodschap = function (tekst) {
        var berichtvenster = document.getElementById('berichtvenster');
        berichtvenster.innerHTML += "<p>" + tekst + "</p>\n";
    };


    var attack = {};
    attack.keuze = prompt("Je volk wordt aangevallen door goblins uit de bergen van doom!         Ga je vechten, vluchten of battlen?").toLowerCase();

    switch (attack) {

    case 'vechten':
        var zwaard = {};
        zwaard.vechter prompt("Heel goed! Heb je sterke zwaardvechters (ja of nee)?").toLowerCase();
        if (zwaard.vechter === "ja") {
            toonBoodschap("Je bent goed voorbereid! Het volk duimt voor je! KOM OP!!");
        } else {
            toonBoodschap("Aaah, zo ga je het niet overleven. Evengoed succes!");
        }
        break;

    case 'vluchten':
        var ren = {};
        ren.hard = prompt("Kan je hard rennen? (ja of nee)?").toLowerCase();
        if (ren.hard === 'ja') {
            toonBoodschap("Je leeft nog! Maar of je volk hetzelfde kan zeggen blijft onbekend...");
        } else {
            toonBoodschap("Dat is jammer, je ziet eruit als een sprinter. Maar blijkbaar niet.");
        }

        break;
    case 'battlen':
        var vecht = {};
        vecht.snel prompt("Okay! Kan je vechten!? (ja of nee)?").toLowerCase();
        if (vecht.snel === 'ja') {
            toonBoodschap("Wow! Dat scheelde weinig. Volgende keer iets minder drinken!");
        } else {
            toonBoodschap("Het lijkt erop dat je karate lessen moet nemen!");
        }
        break;

    }

    var feedback = {};
    feedback.score = prompt("Beoordeel het spel van 1 tot 10");

    if (feedback.score >= 10) {
        toonBoodschap("Dit is slechts het begin van mijn game ontwikkeling, kijk uit voor meer!");
    } else {
        (feedback.score <= 10);
        toonBoodschap("Ik heb als een slaaf geleefd om deze game te maken! En dit is je score! Wacht maar jij!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's actually going wrong?

Comment: Please provide details of what is wrong. Do you get an error? When does the error happen?

Comment: If you don't say *what* you think is going wrong, I can only suspect that the code does what it was written to do.

Comment: He will not launch when i open the HTML (index) there is no popup with (e volk wordt aangevallen door goblins uit de bergen van doom!         Ga je vechten, vluchten of battlen?") after attack.keuze!

Answer (score 2):

I can see one problem:

```
vecht.snel prompt("Okay! Kan je vechten!? (ja of nee)?").toLowerCase();
```

Should be:

```
vecht.snel = prompt("Okay! Kan je vechten!? (ja of nee)?").toLowerCase();
```

EDIT: Just check all the lines where you're adding a prompt to your JS objects that you are assigning the value correctly. There are a couple of "=" missing.

Comment: Thanks! this helps! But now i have the next error: he shows volk wordt aangevallen door goblins uit de bergen van doom! Ga je vechten, vluchten of battlen?") after attack.keuze. But when i typ in vechten (also a case) i go directly to the feedback.score. So he skippes the cases?